# Regular expression matching something except if something is inside html-tags

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Let's say I want to match all numbers (\d+) not inside html tags in the following example. What should the pattern be to capture all the 1s and 4s, but not the 2s and 3s?

```
var pattern = /***************/g;
var string = "asdasd 1111<a href="2222">3333</a>asdasd 4444 asdasasd";
var results = string.match(pattern);
```

results should be this list:

```
>>> results

["1111", "4444"]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: StackOverflow should just automatically redirect any question that references HTML and Regex to that post.

Comment: "Regex cannot parse HTML"

Comment: @maček And in an ideal world these ever-repeating questions would be deleted right away instead of having us go through the same ritual again and again and again.